# vs code microsoft c/c++ extension is not auto closing "<"bracket in inlude header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I write `#include <` it gives me options,
but when I select one of them
it doesn't close the `<` bracket.
I must write the `>`  my self and then go to new line.
It's supposed to be automatically, how to fix that?

Comment: Mine doesn't either. Are you sure it's supposed to do that?